# What does WE8DEC mean?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, character-set

It is one of the commonly used character sets. What does it stand for?

Is it an acronym for something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WE8DEC is the old [DEC MCS character set](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/dec-mcs.html) which stood for Digital Equipment Corporation Multinational Character Set.  The WE8 prefix identifies this as a Western European 8-bit character set.

Comment: How the mighty have fallen... DEC now exists in only legacy nomenclature... sigh.